# How to detect a string is a windows path format in Rust?

Tags: windows, rust, path

It is understood: PathBuf::from doesn't check that the path will be accepted. The only thing it checks is that the path is encoded correctly.

```
fn check(path: &str) -> bool {
    //DO CHECK
}
```

So how do I judge that a string is a valid windows-path, regardless of whether it exists;

Whether it can only be matched by regular expressions？I found a regex at [Windows Path Regex - RegExr](https://regexr.com/52is4) : `/^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\s\.]+\\[\w\s\.$]+)\\(?:[\w\s\.]+\\)*[\w\s\.]*?$/` .

After testing the above regex, it cannot be used in rust.

```rust
if ! Regex::new(r"^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\s\.]+\\[\w\s\.$]+)\\(?:[\w\s\.]+\\)*[\w\s\.]*?$").unwrap().is_match(r"D:\test") {
    println!("Link Path [{}] is invalid.", r"D:\test");
    return;
}
```

Error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Syntax(
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
regex parse error:
    ^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\s\.]+\\[\w\s\.$]+)\\(?:[\w\s\.]+\\)*[\w\s\.]*?$
                ^^
error: unrecognized escape sequence
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
)'
```

Comment: The regex in your code does not match the regex in the error message. Nor does it match the regex that you found (there are differing numbers of backslashes).

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, I have edited; but the problem is still there, can you help me analyze it.@cdhowie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\:` is not a valid escape sequence in Rust regexes.  Presumably, the regex dialect this regex was written for accepts `\:` to mean a literal `:`.  Either the `:` character is special in this dialect, or the dialect permits escaping non-special characters (that is, it would treat `\:` and `:` as equivalent).  Rust regexes do not support escaping non-special characters.

In this case, the solution appears to be to simply to replace `\:` with `:` as the regex seems to be handling a Windows/DOS drive letter.  After this change, [the regex is successfully parsed and appears to work correctly](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=75ef721f2c6b02ca18288acd59bb1a3c) in the sample case provided in your question.

Comment: thanks，Is there any other way besides using regex? On the premise of not using three-party dependencies.

Comment: @KerwinBryant There's always hand-crafted parsers, if you want to roll one yourself. It depends what your goal is.

Comment: My goal is as described above, I hope to detect whether a string is a legal windows resource path; the above sample code can achieve my goal, but because of the introduction of regex, my binary package has increased from 300KB to 1M, So what I'm asking is, as I originally asked, is there a method in the standard library that would satisfy my goal?

Comment: I think of a solution. For example, if I want to judge whether [X:\xyz] is a legal windows resource path, I can intercept root: [\xyz], and then splice the remaining path into %temp%: [%temp%\xyz], and then create this directory, if it can be successfully created, it is considered legal; otherwise, it is not legal;
Why not create [X:\xyz] directly, because the disk [X] may not exist, but it does not affect [X:\xyz] is a legal windows resource path format.

Comment: https://crates.io/crates/test_path

Comment: @KerwinBryant It's not clear if your goal is to determine if the path is syntactically valid or whether it refers to a location your program can write to. If it is the latter, the usual approach is to _just try to write there_ and report an error if you cannot, and thereby side-step validation entirely.